# Imagick fails resizing GIF images when file size is larger than 2mb

Tags: php, imagemagick, gif, image-resizing, imagick

I'm using Imagick PHP extension for resizing GIF images to several sizes. When I trying with a GIF image of 3mb size, it doesn't get resized. But for images less than 1mb, they are getting resized successfully.

If anyone else has faced this problem, please advise!

Here my code

```
if ($extension === 'gif') {
    $imagick =  new Imagick($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

    foreach ($imageFolders as $imageFolder => $size) {

        if ($imagick->getImageWidth() > $size['minWidth']) {
            $width = $size['maxWidth'];
            $height = $size['maxWidth'];
        } else {
            $width = $imagick->getImageWidth();
            $height = $imagick->getImageHeight();

        }

        $imagick->coalesceImages();

        do {
            $imagick->scaleImage($width, $height, Imagick::FILTER_BOX, 1);
        } while ($imagick->nextImage());

        $imagick = $imagick->deconstructImages();
        $imagick->writeImages($imagePath, true);

    }

    $imagick->clear();
    $imagick->destroy();

}
```

Result : convert list resource

```
File         Area       Memory          Map         Disk    Thread         Time
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 768      7.951GB    3.7025GiB    7.4049GiB    unlimited         2    unlimited
```

Comment: Please show your commands? What is your version of Imagemagick? What are the input image dimensions and the resized dimensions? What limits are in your Imagemagick policy.xml file? What error message do you get? Can you do the same resize in Imagemagick command line? Does that work? Perhaps the server has put limitations on the input or output file size?

Comment: @fmw42  I've update the question. Im not using command, im using imagick php code. myserver allowed to mx_upload_filesize is 300m. im not using imagemagicpolicy.xml? do I need to use it with php pls advice

Comment: Are you sure about the upload_max_filesize as 300M sounds a lot, my server limit is 2M. What is post_max_size set at?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.coalesceimages.php#Hcom110393 This seems to have all you need

Comment: @user3647971 I used the same way.  but on my system each image has to  resize into 6 different sizes based on the width/height comes from the foreach loop. when I try to upload a file with 3mb size it either resize into one size and other sizes won't generate else non of the sizes getting resizes

Comment: I'd focus on the first comment and the fact he's drawing gif's separate images there and resizing all of them a bit different than you do

Comment: @user3647971 : so you suggesting me to use the way similar to first comment.? but that need some additonla paramaets , crop_w crop_h crop_x crop_y. where as in my case i do only have 6 different widths and heights . pls advice

Comment: $imagick->coalesceImages() returns a new imagick object that have sets of images

Comment: Just ignore the crop part, the 2 rows below are good for this

Comment: I put in the answers the implementation

Comment: Just a question tho, do you change the imagepath ever?

Comment: Just a point of information. Imagick uses Imagemagick to do its work. So the version of Imagemagick and its policy.xml file may be important. I still suspect either code issues or server limitations as you are dealing with multiple frames and multiple output images. So you are likely using more memory than allows to hold both the input and outputs in memory.

Comment: @fmw42 : you mean server memory ? or something which need to configure through imagemagick?

Comment: The server may have its own memory limitations. Imagemagick has its own limitations that can be changed by editing the policy.xml file. I do not know where you limitation is.

Comment: @fmw42 : here is my current configs max_file_uploads 20 / memory_limit 128m /upload_max_filesize 300m.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know where the comes from. You may set some values somewhere, but your hosting provider may put other limits on the server or even on PHP file sizes or on Imagick. Check your php.ini file to see if there are further restrictions or check with your hosting provider.

Comment: CONTINUED: One way to test this hypothesis, is to simply copy one animation to an output animation. See if the same problem occurs. That avoids any complicated Imagick coding issues.

Comment: @fmw42 I guess php.ini settings are ok since, I used wideimage extesnion  for other image uploads [except gifs] and it works well there for larger images. May I know how can I set or override imagick configs or what settings do I need to adjust. When I try resizing for one size it works. but when looping only im getting issues that also for bigger files . pls advice

Comment: Imagemagick contains a policy.xml file. You can edit that. See https://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php and https://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php#environment. On my Mac, that file resides at /usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml. I do not know if the default configuration will limit your file size, but if you do not have enough RAM, Imagemagick will use disk in its place. But it will just take a very long time. I still suspect your limitation is not with Imagemagick but from your hosting provider. Did you try using Imagick to copy one animation to another? Does that work?

Comment: @fmw42 I've tested with runing one iteration of foraeach loop (one image size), tried with 9mb gif image and still it generated a failed file with 4kb.

Comment: @fmw42 policy.xml is not located on above path in my pc. Is it must to have it? shall add it

Comment: My location is for unix. Windows will have a different location. You will have to search for it. I do not know where it is located on Windows, but it will be there. You can see your current limitations using `convert -list resource`

Comment: @fmw42  : # imagemagick as PHP extension
RUN apt-get install -y libmagickwand-6.q16-dev --no-install-recommends \
 && ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-Q16/MagickWand-config /usr/bin \
 && pecl install imagick \
 && echo "extension=imagick.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini

Comment: @fmw42 above command I used to install imagick as php . That doenst creating any policy.xml file. May I know is it must to have policy.xml file?

Comment: Imagemagick gets installed with Imagick. So there is a full Imagemagick install somewhere on your system with a policy.xml file somewhere. It always gets installed with Imagemagick. I know little about how Imagick is installed. I am sorry I cannot help much further. See http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.getresource.php for using Imagick to list your resources.

Comment: @fmw42 yes I run the command(convert -list resource). pls check the bottom of my question I pasted the result there. Can I add my question to imagick Forum :| ? please advice

Comment: Your resources show you are allowed 3.7 GB RAM. That should be enough. Post to the Imagemagick Discourse server (either the Users forum or the Imagick forum) at https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/. Perhaps someone there has a better recommendation. I still think your problem is a limitation from your hosting provider in the server or how they set up PHP or Imagick. What is the width and height of your image? Sometimes there are limitations on certain format widths.

Comment: @fmw42 : its 7mb file with  480*258

Comment: @fmw42 https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=33372&p=152954#p152954 added my question here too :|

Comment: @F21 Can you check this pls

Answer (score 0):

```
$imagick =  new Imagick($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

foreach ($imageFolders as $imageFolder => $size) {

    if ($imagick->getImageWidth() > $size['minWidth']) {
        $width = $size['maxWidth'];
        $height = $size['maxWidth'];
    } else {
        $width = $imagick->getImageWidth();
        $height = $imagick->getImageHeight(
    }

    $imagick = $imagick->coalesceImages();

    foreach($imagick as $frame){
        $frame->thumbnailImage($width , $height ); 
        $frame->setImagePage($width , $height , 0, 0); 
    }

    $imagick = $imagick->deconstructImages();
    $imagick->writeImages($imagePath, true);

}

$imagick->clear();
$imagick->destroy();
```

Comment: I tryied this way and I could resize and upload a 7mb image. but when i checked the resized images , some of them are not having exact same animation. when comparing with original some animation are slower may be frames are missing or something. Any reason or fix for that?

Comment: Maybe raise another question for it?

Comment: It's hard to debug, there could be number of reasons the play or be slower

Comment: For example, it's a 7mb gif, so maybe browser is having hard time to buffer it

Comment: yes I hope so, because it take some time to complete the resizing process. may be buffer time. Can you advice me any solution for that ?

Comment: You might want to add the Imagick equivalent of -layers optimize before the output, if you are dealing with gif animations. Also I do not see where you set the delay or nor the disposal method.

Comment: Propably because it is not there. According to documentation $imagick->coalesceImages() composites all the frames in the gif while respecting the original disposal methods and delays. I have not fiddled with imagemagick in a while so I wouldn't know about the layers optimize sry

Comment: In Imagemagick, -coalesce does not do any composites. It only fills out the optimized frame that may be smaller than the image to the full image dimensions. The -layer optimize, then re-optimizes the frames so that it can remove unneeded regions that the animation will fill in later with the disposal method. I assume Imagick coalesceImage does the same.

Comment: @fmw42 : How to set delay or disposal when resizing same image to multiple sizes?

Comment: As I do not know Imagick well, you would have to explain is your input an animated gif or a single frame gif? Then when you resize are you resizing the animated gif to different size animations or just resizing the single frame gif to different sizes? See this link http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php for Imagick commands to set delay and disposal, e.g. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagedelay.php and http://us3.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagedispose.php. Delay and disposal are only important if modifying or creating animations.

Comment: @fmw42 my inputs are animated gifs (basically downloading from gihpy site) what I want is to resize and save that gif into 6 different sizes without breaking the animations , so all the resized images should have same animation as original image. only size will be differ

Comment: The code above should produce the desired result here. The delay and disposal are copied over from the original, just the size is altered

Comment: `@user3647971` I do not know Imagick that well. But getting the delay and disposal from the input should work fine. If you have coalesced the frames, you might do http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.optimizeimagelayers.php to re-optimize them. But that should not limit the size of the input animation. My best guess is that there is some server, PHP or Imagick limitation set for the file size.

Comment: @user3647971 : code doen't resize some sizes when uploading larger gifs (5mb -9mb). it only works for 2 sizes and then it stops. any fix?

Comment: @fmw42 : can you pls advice me, when i check larger images it didnt return the width and heights. its return the value as 1. any reason ?

Comment: @user3647971 can you pls advice me, when i check larger images it didnt return the width and heights. its return the value as 1. any reason ?

Comment: `@SandFer` What command or tool did you use to find the width and height of the larger image?

Comment: @fmw42 700*394 dimension image with 9.1mb  here the command $imagick->getImageWidth()

Comment: `@SandFer`  Sorry, I am not an Imagick expert. But it would seem that if your image is not loaded (because it is too big for the system limits), then you would not get the width and would likely get an error flag such as possibly 1.